# Getting Started with UX Research

Tags: user-research, research

I would like to study photographers' digital workflows. What are some good tools and methods for collecting digital workflow data?

Comment: This isn't an answerable question, you're requesting a list of resources, techniques, software etc for creating UX research. That is far too broad, and there isn't a correct answer to such questions. We need *specific* UX questions about a particular issue you have that you're looking for the answer to. There is no problem here that can be solved with an answer, just a request list of tools. Unfortunately due to how Stack Exchange sites work such questions aren't a good fit for the format.

Answer (score 2):

UX is a mix of others subjects(ergonomics, information architecture, interaction design, user centred design, fisiology etc), so it is really complicated to suggest you a start point.

You can start reading those articles:
[nngroup](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/)

Learn some UX (and not) research methods:
[Service deign tools](http://www.servicedesigntools.org/)

And some UX tools:[UX Mastery](http://uxmastery.com/resources/tools/)

Answer (score 1):

Christian,

6 months generally is a very good amount of time for a MVP. For the research the core of this is to try and be as close to user's context as possible. So if possible go and observe people while they work, interview them.

Here are some questions you can use in your research: http://alokjain.pbworks.com/w/page/12300941/by%20Jared%20Spool

and here are some links to read about ethnography
http://alokjain.pbworks.com/w/page/12300943/Ethnography